# read UDPv4 [ENETUNREACH]: Network is unreachable (fd=3,code=101)

Tags: linux

i'm trying to ssh into target machine but on the open vpn terminal i get network unreachable.

using a virtual machine on the website everything works fine

message:
2023-10-04 03:28:07 read UDPv4 [ENETUNREACH]: Network is unreachable (fd=3,code=101)
2023-10-04 03:28:11 read UDPv4 [ENETUNREACH]: Network is unreachable (fd=3,code=101)
2023-10-04 03:28:19 read UDPv4 [ENETUNREACH]: Network is unreachable (fd=3,code=101)
2023-10-04 03:28:36 read UDPv4 [ENETUNREACH]: Network is unreachable (fd=3,code=101)
2023-10-04 03:29:09 read UDPv4 [ENETUNREACH]: Network is unreachable (fd=3,code=101)